# appendCodePoint() and codePointAt()

Tags: java, string

Why does the following program print false, and what changes would I have to make to make it print true?

```
public class Main {

    static int[] codePoints(String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        int[] temp = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            temp[i] = s.codePointAt(i);
        return temp;
    }

    static String construct(int[] codePoints) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i : codePoints)
            sb.appendCodePoint(i);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("The symbol ");
        sb.appendCodePoint(Character.MAX_VALUE + 1);
        sb.append(" is not in the Basic Multilingual Plane.");
        String s = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(s.equals(construct(codePoints(s))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, do you use Java 8?

Comment: No, I'm using Java 6 I think.

Comment: Hmwell, for starters one code point can be two characters wide; you should test, when you get a .codePointAt() some index, whether the result is greater than `Character.MAX_VALUE`; if so you need to grab your next code point _two_ characters after, not one

Comment: (and I mentioned Java 8 because it has a very convenient `.codePoints()` method on `CharSequence` which `String` implements and which returns an `IntStream`...)

Comment: I mostly program for android so I haven't bothered to upgrade Java. Your explanation doesn't quite make sense to me. A code point is an `int`, which is twice as wide as an `char`. Plus if I change the line to `temp[i] = s.codePointAt(i + 1);` I get a `StringIndexOutOfRangeException`, so there are no more indices I can pass to the `codePointAt()` method. It's very strange. I'm obviously missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
static int[] codePoints(String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    int[] temp = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        temp[i] = s.codePointAt(i); // <-- HERE
    return temp;
}
```

A code point outside the BMP is *two* `char`s wide, not one (see [`Character.toChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars-int-)); you need to check that and advance your index if you encounter such a code point:

```
static int[] codePoints(final String s)
{
    final int len = s.length();
    final int[] ret = new int[s.codePointCount(0, len)];
    int nrCodePoints = 0;
    int codePoint;
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        codePoint = s.codePointAt(index);
        ret[nrCodePoints++] = codePoint;
        if (codePoint > Character.MAX_VALUE)
            index++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: And one could use `new int[s.codePointCount(0, s.length())]` to determine the number of code points in advance and use `return ret;` instead copying the array. Probably doesn't save performance, as the internal `char[]` would be looped twice (`codePointCount()` has to do that), but the method `codePoints()` would look a bit simpler.

Comment: I see, so in the method `codePointAt(index)` the index refers to the index in the array of `chars`, not in the array of code points. That's insane! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @pbabcdefp yep, Java was born at a time when Unicode did not yet define code points outside the BMP... And it was too late to change `char` ;)

Comment: This is one of the few occasions where C has an advantage over Java, because `wchar_t` could be redefined, so often, `wchar_t` is `uint32_t` already, not `uint16_t`. Whereas `char` in Java couldn't be changed.

Comment: For the records, `Character.MAX_VALUE` will always be 0xFFFF. Code points above that value need a "surrogate pair" in order to be represented in UTF-16. Poor Java! That UCS-2 it was born with was just a dream, and instead of waking up to something more sane like UTF-8 or UTF-32, the dream has become the nightmare of UTF-16.

Comment: @WalterTross well, meh, Java was born when Unicode did not define anything outside the BMP. Historical baggage...